# How to add header in an uploaded PDF using barryvdh/dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am using [barryvdh/dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) in my project to deal with pdfs. Yes as you are thinking with php and Laravel.

In backend, I have a form which uploads a pdf and from the frontend we can download it.
This functionality is working perfectly.

But now I want to add a header in that uploaded pdf to add my project's name.

I have worked with pdf generation by this package so I know how this package works but I can't find anything about editing a pdf.
I have been doing some research on google but can't find anything related to my problem.

I haven't done anything so far related to this so I have no more details or code to show but to clear confusion let me just show you the points you need to keep in mind and forget anything you read till now.

1. I am using barryvdh/dompdf to deal with pdfs.
2. Want to edit a pdf which is uploaded in the system and will be downloaded afterwards.
3. I Want to add a header.

I just have a mere idea(maybe i am wrong) that it can be done at any of the two stages-
 1. At upload time
 2. At download time

**[Note]:** *Please don't close it as off-topic or duplicate or something similair. Please do read the whole post before doing anything like that. Because like I said, I have done some research and haven't found anything.*

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in DOMPDF.

I guess the solution is to either use [native-ish php commands](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php), another package like [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) or to drop the idea altogether.

Comment: Are you sure that by using only DOMPDF what i am seeking can't be achieved?

Comment: And if yes can please provide how to use those things if you know

Comment: You can do it eventually, but not from within DOMPDF. It would require you to parse the entire uploaded PDF, generate a tree from that data, load the parsed tree into a DOMDocument, then inject the necessary elements you want and generate the PDF again with the new elements. Rough estimation is that will take 2-3 weeks of work becausing parsing PDFs is the worst. Point is, just save yourself a lot of time and stress if this isn't a must have in your project.

Comment: DOMPDF cannot import existing PDFs. As Loek suggested, just use [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) to import the pages and add the header with [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) standard methods. Please keep in mind: [You cannot edit a PDF with FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-i-edit-a-pdf-document-with-fpdi/#question-82) but you recreate it!